# Slow javascript time counter on mobile phones

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a counter in javascript to be run on mobile phones, it works on my computer but on my mobile phone the counter goes from 0 to 2 to 4 etc...

I really need this timer to work, and I can not seem to find an answer anywhere. The code works on my computer but I think the Javascript on my phone is slow. Is there an alternative to Javascript, maybe some HTML5 code I don't know of?

**I put this script in the body tag.**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var time = 0;
    setInterval(
        function () {
            time += 1;
            document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = time;
        }, 1000
    );
</script>
```

Comment: Instead of adding 1 to to the time, find the difference between now, and when you started the timer. Set Interval doesn't guarantee it will run in 1000ms, you are asking it to do it more or less every 1000ms.

Comment: @RichBradshaw Thanks, I found a solution. I would "accept answer" if I could :)

Comment: You can write an answer to your own answer and accept it off you like :)

Answer (score 1):

this is a simple counter exapmple

```
function countdown(elementName, minutes, seconds) {
var element,endTime,hours,mins,msLeft,time;
function twoDigits(n) {
    return (n <= 9 ? "0" + n : n);
}
function updateTimer() {
    msLeft = endTime - (+new Date);
    if (msLeft < 1000) {
        element.innerHTML = "countdown's over!";
    } else {
        time = new Date(msLeft);
        hours = time.getUTCHours();
        mins = time.getUTCMinutes();
        element.innerHTML = (hours ? hours + ':' + twoDigits(mins) : mins) + ':' + twoDigits(time.getUTCSeconds());
        setTimeout(updateTimer, time.getUTCMilliseconds() + 500);
    }
}element = document.getElementById(elementName);
endTime = (+new Date) + 1000 * (60 * minutes + seconds) + 500;
updateTimer();}
```

> to call a function

```
countdown("countdown", 1, 5);
countdown("countdown2", 100, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Store start time as time since epoch, which is returned by `Date.now()` function call. Use this to calculate time difference on each call. This is not guaranteed to work better, because problem you're describing is a problem with processing speed, but you will at least keep the right time every call, it won't skip seconds.

Store starting time:

```
var startTime = Date.now();
```

Calculate time difference since previous call:

```
var time = Date.now() - startTime;
```

Time is now in milliseconds, you'll have to divide it by 1000 and round it to lose decimal places:

```
var seconds = Math.round(time / 1000);
```

Example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maremp/gasrv7m8/) (tested in Chrome on iPhone 6, works as expected).

Comment: I still get the 0, 2, 4, 6 counting. When I scroll or tap the screen it works as expected.

Comment: What phone/browser are you using?

Comment: HTC Desire, and default browser. I'm testing it on a bad phone because I assume if it works on a bad phone it'll work on good phone. But I'll test it on as many phones as I can before releasing it.

Comment: It's hard to develop for default browsers on old android devices. Those browsers are poorly developed and do not follow current standards. Btw did you try to implement this in your code, or are you trying out the code directly from my jsfiddle?

Comment: I'm using phoneGap to create a server where I test it.

Comment: So what is it then, phonegap app or android's default browser? Phonegap apps are not running in default browser, they have own emulator. Are you at least using exactly the same code as in my jsfiddle, this is important information.

Answer (score -2):

An optimization would be to select timer and assign it to a variable that is maintained. Then use the variable instead of doing the getElementById call every time. DOM manipulation can be expensive and may be especially so on a mobile device (depending on the device and the DOM).

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var time = 0;
    var timer= document.getElementById("timer");
    setInterval(
        function () {
            time += 1;
            timer.innerHTML = time;
    }, 1000
);
```

Comment: This doesn't solve root of the problem. And it's not even that much of an optimisation, `getElementById` should work fast, since id's are supposed to be unique, therefore it's comparable to accessing a hashmap.

Comment: It would certainly be faster than the original. A fast lookup running all the time is still running all the time.